# Matlab, set font in figure plot

Tags: matlab, fonts, matlab-figure

I try to use the *AvantGarde* font in a MATLAB figure plot.
However on the figure, the font is not displayed.
I have the R2015a MATLAB version on Ubuntu.

When I use the `*listfonts` command, the *AvantGarde* font is listed as available.
When using `uisetfont`, the *AvantGarde* font is working and display without any problems. As shown here (`uisetfont` command):

[image: uisetfont command]

Here is an extraction of my code where i set up the font:

```
fontname = 'AvantGarde';
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName',fontname,'DefaultTextFontName',fontname);
```

Here an extraction of my output where the problems occurs:

[image: output]

I don't understand where the problem comes from and why the choosen font is not used for my figure, any help would be appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you set the default font before you created the figure?

the following example works for me:

```
clear all;
fontname = 'AvantGarde'; 
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName',fontname,'DefaultTextFontName',fontname);
figure;
plot(1:10,1:10);
xlabel('test x');
ylabel('test y');
```

As an Alternative, you can set the appropriate Property after creation of the figure, by storing the handle to the x- and y-label.

```
clear all;
fontname = 'AvantGarde'; 
% set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName',fontname,'DefaultTextFontName',fontname);
figure;
plot(1:10,1:10);
xLabelHandle = xlabel('test x');
yLabelHandle = ylabel('test y');

set(yLableHandle,'Fontname',fontname);
```

Comment: Just realized that when i plot directly in Matlab it's working however the problem occurs when i export the figure in PDF. Either by directly exporting with the *saveas* command in PDF, either by exporting from the matlab plot (the window that opens when you run your code).

Comment: PDF has by default fourteen fonts. If you want to use a custom font like 'AvantGarde', you will have to embed the font into the PDF. Otherwise it will be substituted by one of the default fonts.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did not succeed to find a way to embed the font via Matlab yet but now i know where to look.